# Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 (GT P1000 with 2.2version android) stuck in boot-loop on update to CM10

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, downgrade, boot-loop

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 (GT P 1000) with Android 2.2. A couple of days ago, I decided to update my Tab to JellyBean, and I searched the web for its procedure

I found a [HowTo at AndroidAuthority](http://www.androidauthority.com/galaxy-tab-p1000-android-4-1-1-jelly-bean-cyanogenmod-10-cm10-106995/). After downloading the files and placing them on the internal SD, I followed its procedure about the recovery mode. My tab started to update but in the middle of upgrading it stopped and restarted.

After that, my tab continuously follows this trend 1. Booting 2. Loading the OS 3. Rebooting 4. Go to 1! I could not even return its OS to is previous state!

**I could not even go to the Recovery mode to do something.**

Someone told me that each phone has a ROM or something like downgrading thing which I should download it and follow another procedure. I think I should do something like formatting and reinstalling a fresh, brand new Android OS on it like the procedure when we want to install a new Windows OS on our PC.

Does anybody by any chance know what should I do?

Comment: In short, CM9/10 is horribly broken and especially for a tablet... well... best you can do is to use a [stock firmware](http://samfirmware.com) and flash that manually instead. Give it time for the devs to stabilize it, I have heard of people putting in a P1000 ROM on top of P1010 and vice versa and end up in that situation.

Comment: Did your procedure include wiping App Cache and Dalvik Cache? Did you by any chance miss those steps? In that case, a [factory reset](http://www.hardreset.eu/samsung_galaxy_tab_p1000_hard_reset_soft_reset_en.html) might help. Keep in mind that this deletes all your data -- but that was part of the CM10 upgrade either.